# Is there a gui frontend to configure AutoComplete in Notepad++ for a User Defined Language?

Tags: notepad++

Can `AutoComplete` for a User Defined Language be done via the gui or is it all in XML hand-typed? I only saw UDL for delimeters, keywords, etc. I know the autocomplete keywords and examples are in the API folder, but before I start doing things by hand, I wanted to make sure there is no gui frontend like there is for UDL already.  I've created a UDL from the User Defined Language interface under Language, but I can't find anything for AutoComplete, and most all the docs links for UDL are dead.

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure, if this is what you are looking for. But there is a pretty good plugin called **FingerText** that has a sort of GUI and it quite flexible to create auto-completion. It is more of a snippet completion though. Here are few screenshots to demonstrate.

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps.